# git what's the recommended way to update from old 32bit version to new 64 bit version in windows

Tags: 64-bit, git, cygwin

I want to update my git version from 32bit (v 1.9.5) to the latest version (2.6.3)
I downloaded a 64bit version. Should I stick with 32bit?

As I see it I could uninstall the old version by removing the directories from the PATH.
Then install the new version.

As far as I can tell, the old version uses cygwin, and the new version doesn't?
Do I have to uninstall or update cygwin also if I move to 64 bit?
I like to have cygwin around.

I have started the installer (didn't proceed yet) and the directory defaults to:
`C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git`
Should I go with this or `C:\Program Files\Git` instead?

Answer (score 2):

#### I downloaded a 64bit version. Should I stick with 32bit?

- It is up to you to decide whether the 64bit version is better for your needs.
- You can install/use `git` independently of `cygwin`.
- The latest version of Cygwin `git` is 2.6.2-1 (32bit and 64bit).
- If you want to use 64bit Cygwin then remove the 32bit version (make sure you backup your config files `~/.bashrc` etc - recommended, not essential) and then install the 64bit version.
- 64bit is a different installer as well (http://www.cygwin.net/setup-x86_64.exe)
- Some packages are not available in the 64bit version of Cygwin.